# Why are the kmeans centroids far from the data? Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, sklearn-pandas

I'm making a kmeans model with the data from Twitter, but when I apply the polarity and subjectivity analysis on the scatterplot, the centroids (red x) appear far from the data:

```
     from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
            from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    data = df[['Polarity', 'Subjetivity']].values
    
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

k = 3 
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(scaled_data)
cluster_labels = kmeans.labels_
df['Cluster'] = cluster_labels
centroides = kmeans.cluster_centers_
df_kmeans_center = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': centroides[:,0],
        'x2': centroides[:,1]
    }
)

sns.scatterplot(x='Polarity', y='Subjetivity', hue='Cluster', data=df,
                palette="flare")
sns.scatterplot(data=df_kmeans_center, x='x1', y='x2', marker='X',size=500, color='red')
plt.title('Seg. Tweets')
plt.xlabel('Polarity')
plt.ylabel('Subjetividad')
plt.show()
```

the result is this:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you haven't run the code in that order (if using a notebook for example), so you fitted K-Means _before_ scaling the data?

Answer (score 2):

You can't plot centroids without rescaled them if you plot your real data (without any transformation). You have to inverse the transformation:

```
centroids = scaler.inverse_transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

Demo:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from textblob import TextBlob

# Sample
df = pd.read_csv('vaccination_tweets.csv')
df['Polarity'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).polarity)
df['Subjetivity'] = df.text.apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).subjectivity)

data = df[['Polarity', 'Subjetivity']].values
    
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

k = 3 
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, n_init=10).fit(scaled_data)
cluster_labels = kmeans.labels_
df['Cluster'] = cluster_labels

# Centroid
scaled_centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
real_centroids = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_centroids)

ax = sns.scatterplot(x='Polarity', y='Subjetivity', hue='Cluster', marker='.', data=df, palette='flare')
ax.scatter(real_centroids[:, 0], real_centroids[:, 1], s=100, marker='x', color='red', label='Centroid (real)')
ax.scatter(scaled_centroids[:, 0], scaled_centroids[:, 1], s=100, marker='x', color='green', label='Centroid (scaled)')

plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Nana. Does it solve your problem?